# Column or global variable not found with nested subqueries

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

I have a db2 database with two tables; let's call them `order` and `order_comment`.

What I want is to retrieve the date of the most recent comment along with the order information.

On sql server 2005, for example, I could write a query like the following:

```
select a.*, (select comment_datetime FROM
    (select comment_datetime, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY order_id ORDER BY comment_datetime DESC) AS [rank]
        FROM order_comment c where c.order_id = a.id
    ) b where b.[rank] = 1) as 'Last Comment'
from order a
```

This returns the following data:

```
| id | description |       Last Comment      |
|  1 |  fake order | 2013-04-03 10:05:04.797 |
```

However, when I try to run the following query (what I think is equivalent) against my db2 database, I get this error: `Column or global variable id1 not found.`

```
select b.id1, b.id2, b.status, 
    (select a.code from 
        (select code, RANK() over (order by date desc, time desc) as recent from
            history where h_id1 = b.id1 and h_id2 = b.id2 
                 and code in ('A', 'B', 'C')) a where a.recent = 1)
     as 'recent code'
from item b
```

After some playing around, I discovered that using `id1` in my first sub-query did not yield the same error; I only had an issue when using the global value in a sub-query more than one level deep.

Is this intended behavior? It strikes me as very odd; I'd think that any number of sub-queries should be able to access any values belonging to any parent (as seems to be the case on sql server 2005, and I assume most other RDBMSs).

If this is, in fact, expected behavior, is there any other way I can accomplish this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe on DB2, you have to "bubble up" (or down) any columns you want to use in sub-queries (I.E., it has to be in the immediate parent or sub-query for the column to be accessible).

As an alternative, I think you can get what you're looking for with this query:

```
SELECT 
     b.id1
    ,b.id2
    ,b.status
    ,(SELECT h.code
      FROM history h
      WHERE h.id1 = b.id1
        AND h.id2 = b.id2
        AND code in ('A', 'B', 'C')
      ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC
      FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
     ) AS "Recent Code"
FROM item AS b
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this version in db2:

```
select b.id1, b.id2, b.status, 
       (select code
        from history
        where h_id1 = b.id1 and h_id2 = b.id2 and code in ('A', 'B', 'C') 
        order by DATE desc
        fetch first 1 rows only
       ) as RecentCode
from item b
```